# How to import selenium library using bultin.import_library()

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

So I'm trying to import selenium through python code. This is the code:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
builtin = BuiltIn()
builtin.import_library(r'C:\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary')
```

When I run, I get this error:

```
raise RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')
robot.libraries.BuiltIn.RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context
```

What should I do?

UPDATE: This is the whole code:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

runs = [1, 2, 3]

def run_session():
    builtin = BuiltIn()
    builtin.import_library(r'C:\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary')
    # Some other stuff

for run in runs:
    Thread(target=run_session).start()
```

Then I run this code using this command: `Python test.py`.

Comment: In order for the robot to have any execution context, you'd need to start an execution. How are you executing the Python code here?

Comment: @Morkkis Thanks for your comment. I updated my question to show how I run the code.

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that you're trying to access the library before a test run has started. You can only get an instance of a keyword library after the test has started running.

Comment: thank you very much! Do you have any suggestion for me how to make it run? I have updated my question to give you a better picture.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bryan Oakley mentioned,  You can only get an instance of a keyword library after the test has started running.

For that you should run the robot file first, then you should call the function written in python file using robot file.

example.robot

```
***Settings***
Library    Python test.py

***Test Cases ***
open browser  http://example.com   chrome 
run_thread
```

Python test.py

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

runs = [1, 2, 3]

def run_session():
    builtin = BuiltIn()
    builtin.import_library(r'C:\project\venv\Lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary')
    # Some other stuff
def run_thread():
    for run in runs:
        Thread(target=run_session).start()
```